# check if named xml sitemap node exists

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I am generating an xml sitemap using php by querying a database and adding url nodes as I go. There are some entries in the database that will produce duplicate urls, so would like to check my xml string before adding the next node.`

The process goes...

```
new SimpleXMLElement

$url = $xml->addChild('url');
$url->addChild('loc', 'http://www.example.com/url');
$url->addChild('lastmod', $date);
$url->addChild('changefreq', "Daily");

$xml->asXML("sitemap.xml");
```

Comment: Do you have a question with which we can assist you?

Comment: I would like to check if a node exists before adding it

Answer (score 0):

use `xpath` to check:

```
$pageurl = "http://www.test.com/test"; // URL to check
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);

$set = $xml->xpath("//url[loc = '$pageurl']");
```

Now check if array `$set` contains elements or not...

```
if (! isset($set[0])) {

    echo "$pageurl not found - add it.";

}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/134107